# Post serialised Json body - [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Error-

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cross-platform, mobile-application

I have been stuck for the last 2 days regarding flutter post method with JSON row body, the code which I have tried is shown here.

Code 1:

```
void send() async {

    userModel = UserModel(userName: "usernme", password: "password");

       var response = await http.post(
           "https://stagingapi......",
           headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
           body: json.encode(userModel.toJson()));


       print(response.body);
       print(response.statusCode);

}
```

I have created serialised body Model  like,

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'UserModel.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class UserModel {
  String userName;
  String password;
  // String xyz;
  UserModel({this.userName, this.password});
  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserModelToJson(this);
}
```

Code 2:-

```
Future<User> createUser(String username, String password) async{
  final String apiUrl = "https://stagingapi.....";
  Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};
  final body = jsonEncode({ "userName": username,
    "password": password});
  try {
    var response = await http.post(apiUrl, headers: headers, body: body);
    print(response.statusCode);
    if(response.statusCode == 201){
      final String responseString = response.body;

      return userFromJson(responseString);
    }else{
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    print('error- $error');
   
    }
  }
}
```

In both cases or if I try any post code method it throws the following error,

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: 
#0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:65:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:176:38)
#2      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:58:7)
#3      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:70:16)
#4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
#5      post (package:http/http.dart:69:5)
#6      _SelectDOBState.send (package:kash_app/SelectDOB.dart:99:29)
#7      _SelectDOBState.initState (package:kash_app/SelectDOB.dart:92:6)
#8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4812:57)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4649:5)
#10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3615:14)
#11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3380:18)
#12     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:616<…>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is working in other urls...I have resolved this issue, it was from our backend team made some changes to domain url by adding some `configuration in IIS OR secure certificate related`